# I can't have a beginning value for react-datepicker and still be able to change it from dropdown?

Tags: reactjs, react-datepicker

EDIT: I found the answer, check it below and add these together!

I'm trying to have the `react-datepicker` dropdown menu to show the current `start_time` when it's first loaded and then the user could choose a time they want from the dropdown. Time could then be submitted with a button (not relevant).

At the moment the time slot doesn't show `placeholderText`, it shows current time (my timezone) and it can change into whatever the user chooses. I've tried to put `selected={null}`, which shows the `placeholderText` correctly, but it then won't submit save user's chosen time.

If someone could help me get this to work, I'd appreciate it a lot! The `placeholderText` isn't important, as long as it shows `start_time` first and it can then be changed. Thanks in advance!

`start_time` = `TIME` data type from MySQL (`XX:XX:XX`)
`reservationsData[0]` = `{start_time: 9.00}` etc.
`row` = sets which `start_time` is given

```
class TimeClass extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      time: new Date()
    };
  }

  handleChange = time => {
    this.setState({
      time: time
    });
  }

  render() {
    let showThisFirst = this.props.reservationsData[this.props.row - 1].start_time;

    return (
      <div>
        <DatePicker
          selected={this.state.time}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          placeholderText={moment(showThisFirst, "hh:mm:ss").format("HH.mm")}
          showTimeSelect
          showTimeSelectOnly
          timeIntervals={15}
          dateFormat="HH.mm"
          timeCaption="Time"
          getDefaultLocale="fi"
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**Visually:**

```
|---------|    
|  09.00  | // looks like this when it loads, start_time
|---------|

|---------|    
|  09.00  | // choosing a time to replace 09.00
|---------|
|  08.30  |
|  08.45  |
|  09.00  | 
|  09.15  |
|  09.30  |
|  09.45  |
|  10.00  |
|   ...   |
|---------|

|---------|    
|  09.45  | // when the time is chosen, user changes the start_time
|---------| // no need to submit, just choose. Button next to it handles it
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I found an answer myself!

It was simple, just set `selected={this.state.startTime}` for the `DataPicker` and put `startTime: time` inside `handleChange`.

**In short:**

```
handleChange = time => {
  this.setState({
    startTime: time
  });
}

return (
  <DatePicker
    selected={this.state.startTime}
    onChange={this.handleChange}
    placeholderText={moment(dropPicker, "hh:mm:ss").format("HH.mm")}
  />
);
```